# Which spaces do admit a countable separating family of open sets?

Tags: general-topology

I call a family of subsets of a topological space *separating* if for any two distinct points there is a set in the family containing exactly one of them. I am looking for some (preferably equivalent) conditions under which a space admits a countable separating family of open sets.

If a space is $T_1$ and has a countable base then this countable base is such family. On the other side, any space admitting such family must be $T_0$.

Are there known any other necessary or suffcient conditions for the existence of such family? I am specially interested if the condition "separable and perfectly normal" is sufficient.

*Note*: If the space admits a countable family of open sets separating in a somewhat stronger sense "for any $x\neq y$ there is a set $U$ in the family such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$" then each singleton must be $G_\delta$ and hence the space must be $T_1$. As Henno Brandsma pointed out (his comment has disappeared), there is a cardinal characteristic called *separating weight*, defined as the minimum cardinality of a separating family of open sets, in this stronger sense. Actually, this stronger condition was what I had originally on mind when I asked this question.

Comment: It is not true that every singleton has to be $G_δ$ and the space even doesn't have to be $T_1$. The two-point Sierpinski space satisfies the given condition.

Comment: @user87690 Thank you, you are right.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: How is countable network sufficient? Don't you mean countable pseudobase?

Comment: @user87690 countable network (like a base, but members can be any set) according to the handbook of set-theoretic topology. Pseudobase is what?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Pseudobase is a family of open sets such that every singleton is the intersection of some of them.

Comment: @user87690 Countable pseudoweight (also called countable "separating weight" by Hodel) or $\psi w(X)= \aleph_0$ is by definition the property the OP is asking for except that we then have $T_1$ as a necessary condition. And $\psi w(X) \le nw(X)$ holds for $T_2$ spaces and is 2.8b in Juhasz second cardinal functions book. It's not very hard. The OP was asking for "weak pseudo weight countable", originally, in a way.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put my comments in an answer:

The minimal size of such a point separating family (also called a pseudobase) is called either $\psi w(X)$ (pseudoweight, Juhasz) or $sw(X)$ (separating weight, Hodel). So you ask for conditions that $\psi w(X) = \aleph_0$. $X$ must be $T_1$ for this to be defined at all, as you state.

For $T_2$ spaces we have $\psi w(X) \le nw(X)$ (Juhasz 2nd cardinal functions book 2.8.b), so a $T_2$ space with countable network (a collection like a base but they need not be open sets) will have such a countable family.

A necessary condition is also $|X| \le 2^{\aleph_0}$, or more accurately $\psi w (X) \le \log(|X|)$. A nice paper on this and related cardinal functions is [from Brian M. Scott](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0166864186900209/1-s2.0-0166864186900209-main.pdf?_tid=7e062ac8-fc9d-11e7-aab3-00000aacb361&acdnat=1516314081_08af200aaad47fc323606920b9fc69ee) (also active here). He names this cardinal function $\psi_1(X)$ ($1$ refers to $T_1$).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I am trying to prove that if a quotient space of $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff then it can be injectively and continuously mapped into $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. I already knew that the quotient must be normal (even perfectly normal and separable), but I needed also a countable separating family. Now I am happy since taking a quotient of a space does not increase its network weight.

Comment: @PeterElias indeed it does prove such a Hausdorff quotient condenses onto a separable metric space (i.e. a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$). It’s then a so-called “cosmic space” ( weird name).